# Get youtube playlist by ID in youtube api .net

Tags: c#, .net, api, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to download the most recent items from a YouTube playlist in a C# .NET program. Right now I have a program that successfully gets the necessary data from my channel's Uploads playlist using "channel.ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Uploads;", which I got from the sample program on the API page. But I can't find any information in the api docs about how to switch that line or lines around it to get a playlist by ID rather than my own uploads.

This is not a duplicate because other examples on this page explain how to find it through an http link, as in "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/..." etc. I want to do it directly through the API's methods. The part of my code that downloads the data is included below.

```
private async Task Run()
{
    var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        ApiKey = "API KEY HERE",
        ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
    });

    //MAYBE I NEED TO CHANGE THIS? SOMETHING LIKE
    //'youtubeservice.Playlists.IDUNNOWHAT'
    var channelsListRequest = youtubeService.Channels.List("contentDetails");
    channelsListRequest.Id = "CHANNEL ID HERE";

    // Retrieve the contentDetails part of the channel resource for the authenticated user's channel.
    var channelsListResponse = await channelsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();
    foreach (var channel in channelsListResponse.Items)
    {


        //OR MAYBE I NEED TO CHANGE THIS PART? 
        //LIKE 'channel.ContentDetails.SOMETHING
        var uploadsListId = channel.ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Uploads;


        var nextPageToken = "";
        while (nextPageToken != null)
        {
            var playlistItemsListRequest = youtubeService.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
            playlistItemsListRequest.PlaylistId = uploadsListId;
            playlistItemsListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
            playlistItemsListRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;

            // Retrieve the list of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
            var playlistItemsListResponse = await playlistItemsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();
            /*
            * DO A BUNCH OF STUFF WITH THE YOUTUBE DATA
            */
            nextPageToken = playlistItemsListResponse.NextPageToken;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What other playlist(s) are you trying to get?

Comment: A playlist I have created. I need to get it by its ID. In other words, I put in the ID of the playlist and get back a list of videos on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists), it lists the playlists you can get by using `ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists`:

> - likes
> - favorites
> - uploads
> - watchHistory
> - watchLater

Therefore, if you want to get the items for a playlist you created you won't be able to do it using `ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists`, you'll have to provide the playlist ID. I believe it should work with the code you provided (might need a few tweaks) if you change

```
playlistItemsListRequest.PlaylistId = uploadsListId;
```

to use the ID of the playlist whose videos you want to get.